# Eigenvalues of a matrix close to a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> I am trying to find all the eigenvalues of $P$ defined below:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0.5&0.5&0&0&\cdots 0&0 \\
0.25&0.5&0.25&0&\cdots 0&0\\
0&0.25&0.5&0.25&\cdots 0&0\\
\vdots \\
0&0&0&0&\cdots 0.5&0.5
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

So $P$ has $0.5$ along the main diagonal. It has $0.25$ on diagonals above and below the main diagonal except for the first and last row. Hence $P$ is not exactly a Toeplitz matrix.

**My attempt:** A [paper](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-password/21-24-2006/salkuyehIMF21-24-2006.pdf) I'm looking at, gives eigenvalues of the following Toeplitz matrix

$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
b&a \\
c&b&a \\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots \\
&&c&b&a \\
&&&c&b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

as $\lambda_j = b+2\sqrt{ca}\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{n+1} \right)$

So I'm wondering if I will be able to find eigenvalues of $P$ even though its not a Toeplitz matrix precisely?

Comment: I suspect that [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#The_discrete_case) could be helpful

Comment: You have a typo in the eiegenvalues of the Toeplitz matrix, the coefft of the $\cos$ has to be $2\sqrt{ac}$.

Comment: There's clearly an eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $1$ and another $1$ of multiplicity $1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks, corrected the typo.

Comment: Did u try to look at $Px = \lambda x$ and expand linear equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\a{\alpha}$
Let $u$ be an eigenvector of the matrix $P$ and assume the elements of the eigenvector have the form:
$$
u_k=e^{\alpha k}+ae^{-\alpha k},\tag1
$$
with some parameters $a$ and $\alpha$, which are to be found.

Obviously for all $k=2\dots(n-1)$
$$
(Pu)_k=\frac14\left(e^{\a k}+ae^{-\alpha k}\right)\left(e^\alpha+2+e^{-\alpha}\right)
=\frac14\left(e^\alpha+2+e^{-\alpha}\right)u_k.\tag2$$

Thus it remains only to find such $a$ and $\alpha$ that the equation $(2)$ is satisfied for $k=1$ and $k=n$ as well.

For $k=1$:
$$\begin{align}
&\frac12(e^{\a}+ae^{-\a}+e^{2\a}+ae^{-2\a})=\frac14\left(e^\a+2+e^{-\a}\right)\left(e^\alpha+a e^{-\alpha}\right)\\
&\iff
e^{2\a}+ae^{-2\a}=1+a \iff a=e^{2\a}.\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

For $k=n$:
$$\begin{align}
&\frac12(e^{\a(n-1)}+ae^{-\a(n-1)}+e^{\a n}+ae^{-\a n})
=\frac14\left(e^\a+2+e^{-\a}\right)\left(e^{\a n}+a e^{-\a n}\right)\\
&\iff e^{\a (n-1)}+ae^{-\a(n-1)}=e^{\a (n+1)}+ae^{-\a(n+1)}\\
&\iff e^{\a (n-1)}+ae^{-\a (n-1)}=e^{2\a}e^{\a(n-1)}+ae^{-2\a}e^{-\a(n-1)}\\
&\stackrel{(3)}\iff \left(e^{\a (n-1)}-e^{-\a (n-1)}\right)\left(1-e^{2\a}\right)=0\\
&\iff \a_m=\frac{\pi\,i}{n-1}m,\quad m=0\dots n-1
.\tag{4}
\end{align}$$

The corresponding eigenvalues are:
$$
\lambda_m=\frac14\left(e^{\a_m}+2+e^{-\a_m}\right)=\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\a_m}2}+e^{-\frac{\a_m}2}}2\right)^2=\cos^2\frac{\pi m}{2(n-1)},\quad m=0\dots n-1.\tag5
$$
Since all $n$ eigenvalues are distinct we are done.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at $(5)$ now, how do you have $\frac{e^{\alpha_m/2}+e^{-\alpha_m/2}}{2}=\cos\left( \frac{\alpha_m}{2} \right)$?

Comment: @manifolded I used: $\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2=\cos x$

Comment: I see, I missed the $i$ in $\alpha_m$ earlier. Thanks.

Comment: I see that $(Pu)_k = \frac{1}{4}(e^{(k-1)\alpha}+ae^{-(k-1)\alpha})+\frac{1}{2}(e^{k\alpha}+ae^{-k\alpha})+\frac{1}{4}(e^{(k+1)\alpha}+ae^{-(k+1)\alpha})$, for $k=2,\cdots,n-1$, by definition of matrix multiplication but that is not equal to $(2)$?

Comment: @manifolded It is equal, with no doubt.

Comment: May I know the intuition behind choosing $u_k=e^{\alpha k}+ae^{-\alpha k}$? Thanks.

Comment: I invented this tool several years ago working on a similar problem. It works whenever $(Au_k)=bu_{k-1}+au_{k}+bu_{k+1}$ for all $k$ except for the boundary. The intuition behind: this looks like a discrete version of the linear differential equation of second order which usually has general solution $A_1e^{\lambda_1x}+A_2e^{\lambda_2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

(Not a solution)

I *numerically* found that the answer should be
$$
\lambda_j = \sin^{2}\left(\frac{j\pi}{2(n-1)}\right), \quad 0\leq j \leq n-1
$$
but I only have a vague idea to prove this. If we define $B_n = 2P_n - I_n$, then it is enough to show that the eigenvalues of $B_n$ are
$$
\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{n-1}\right),\quad 0\leq j\leq n-1.
$$
It seems that the characteristic polynomial of $B_n$ is
$$
\phi_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^{n}}(x^2-1)U_{n-2}(x)
$$
where $U_n(x)$ is $n$-th [Chebyshev polynomial of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). However, I'm not sure how to prove this, although it seems that using induction might give recurrence formula for $\phi_n$ which resembles that of $U_n$ a lot.

Comment: For the numerical solution, may I know if you found $\lambda_j^{(n)}$ for different $n$ and then conclude $\lambda_j$ is what you have above? Thanks.

Comment: @manifolded Yes, I just plotted the eigenvalues and it reminds me $\sin^2$.

Comment: May I know why it is enough for $B_n$ to have its eigenvalues as $\cos \left(\frac{j\pi}{n-1} \right)$? I didn't understand how $B_n=2P_n-I_n$ implies that?

Comment: @manifolded It follows from $\sin^2(x)=(1-\cos(2x))/2$.

Comment: I see, I thought if $B_n$ has eigenvalues of $\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{n-1} \right)$, then $\frac{I_n-B_n}{2}$ will have eigenvalues $\sin^2 \left(\frac{j\pi}{2(n-1)} \right)$ as opposed to $\frac{I_n+B_n}{2}$ which is what you have. I maybe wrong?